# The GET Request is successful through PostMan but is giving a 308 Permanent Redirect through Spring RestTemplate Exchange Method Call

Tags: get, spring-resttemplate, http-status-code-308

The GET Request contains a JSON Payload similar to below :
{
"customeId" : "A123",
"Status" : "Assigned",
"StartDate" : "2020-07-18",
"EndDate" : "2020-07-20",
"FetchLimit" : "10"
}
Am using multi-value map to add these inputs along with Headers (Content-type,Accept,Co-relation ID). The same request payload is providing the response thru Postman, but when I make a GET call using
RestTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.Get ,entity, Response.class) am receiving Response as 308 PERMANENT REDIRECT.
Any thoughts towards resolution would be great ! TIA
###Code Snip Below####

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("Accept",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.set("Correlation-ID","1234");
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("customerId","A123");
    map.add("status","Assigned");
    map.add("StartDate","2020-07-18");
    map.add("EndDate","2020-07-19");
    map.add("FetchLimit","10");
    String urlString = "http://dev-editest.com/cust/v1/retreiveById"
    HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
    ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.exchange(urlString, HttpMethod.GET, request, User.class);
```

Comment: Show us the Java code please..

Comment: Hi Giorgi - Am unable to share the code as its a restricted machine. So am summarizing the issue. Let me try to replicate it on my machine and share. Thanks for the response

Comment: The code snipped has been added for reference